# Why instance variable with default access modifier can't be found in subclass?

Tags: java

I'm learning about the access modifiers for classes and instance variables. I know that default access modifier can be accessed within the package.

But I can't understand why this code doesn't work:

### `A.java :`

This is the super class file with just one instance variable with `default` access.

```java
package foo;
public class A {
    int a = 10;
}
```

### `B.java :`

Subclass file within the same package `foo`, which tries to use instance variable `a` of superclass `class A`

```java
package foo;
class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.test();
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Variable is : " + a);
    }
}
```

This program is supposed to work, but I got `cannot find symbol` error.

```
B.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
class B extends A {
                ^
    symbol: class A
B.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.println("Variable is : " + a);
                                                      ^
    symbol:     variable a
    location:   class B
2 errors
```

What is the reason for this error because as per the rule instance variable with `default` access modifier can be accessed with in a package. Here, the `class A` is public so it is visible to the `class B`. Instance variable `a` of `class A` has `default` access, so it can be accessed if the `class A` is extended by other classes within the same package.

Comment: Seems you have a more serious problem which the compiler tells you about: "cannot find symbol", "class A"

Comment: @greedybuddha: No, that's not the problem at all. The problem is that the compiler doesn't even know what A is...

Comment: @greedybuddha I think default access modifier is visible to the subclass if the subclass and superclass share the same package. By both method via the reference of superclass and with the inheritance also!!!

Comment: My comment was because I didn't see that they were in the same package. I also missed the `cannot find symbol`.  my comment is already deleted

Comment: It just works, my output is `Variable is : 10`. You have errors because the compiler can't find the `A` class. Obviously, without the `A` class, you won't be able to read it's fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that compiler cannot find class A. Once it can do it it can find the member `a` as well. You problem is probably in the manner you are running java compiler. I believe that you are compiling from command line, aren't you?

In this case you have to be where your source root is. Then run `javac foo/B.java`. This should work without problems.

While you continue pay attention on command line options `-classpath` and `-sourcepath`. Then I'd recommend you to start using IDE.

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling from the command line. And yes you're right the problem is the way i'm compiling my program. I've tried `javac foo/B.java` and it works. Hey! I'm a new to Java, can you tell me why i should have to go up too `foo` for compiling. Thanks!!

Comment: @parth, congratulations. Glad to know you managed to do this. The reason is that you always have to compile when you are in root. However compiler cannot find dependencies. You have to specify `foo` because this is your package name and otherwise compiler cannot find your class.

Comment: Got it!! I'm compiling from the inside of the package directory. But I have to compile always from the outside of the package directory so that every file is accessible to the compiler, Right? Now, I have to pick one IDE because it turns out into a silly question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've dumped both classes into the current directory (or similar). They will need to be in called `foo` with correct file name (`A.java`). And your compiler classpath (or sourcepath) set to the directory containing the `foo` directory.

A clue is you have two error messages. Usually it's best to sort the first one out first, as subsequent messages may become odd.

Comment: Thanks! And Why I have to compile from the `foo` directory?

Comment: @parth javac needs to be able to find the classes by path name. If you have lots of files, you wouldn't necessarily want to compile them all just to find the right class.